# MobileFirst 8.0 Cordova CLI Interface not found in app preview (MAC)

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I have successfully started the server, registered the app and deployed all adapters. However, whenever I call the command:

> mfpdev app preview

The CLI is responding with the following message:

> [BS] Serving files from: ./platforms
>   Error: The Cordova command-line interface is not installed on your system path.

Of course I have previously checked that Cordova is available, by using cordova -v (I am gettint '6.1')

What could be the problem?

I'm using OSX El Capitan 10.11.3

Update:

mfpdev info command shows the following information:

> Cordova information:
>     Version: 6.3.1
>     Installed plug-ins:
>       cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
>       cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
>       cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.2.1 "Notification"
>       cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.3 "Globalization"
>       cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2016080320 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
>       cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
>       cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
>       cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
>       cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
>       ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
>     Installed platforms:
>     android 5.2.2
>     ios 4.2.1
>
> Cordova app configuration:
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation namespace: http://www.ibm.com/mobilefirst/cordova-plugin-mfp
>       Widget ID: com.ionicframework.todo107397
>       Widget version: 0.0.1
>       Widget name: todo
>       Main file: index.html
>       MobileFirst SDK checksum for Android: 1638037605
>       MobileFirst SDK checksum for iOS: 2417110129
>       MobileFirst SDK checksum for Windows 10 UWP: 0
>       MobileFirst SDK checksum for Windows 8 desktop: 0
>       MobileFirst SDK checksum for Windows Phone 8: 0
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation platform version: 8.0.0.00-20160803-1114
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation client custom init: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation server URL: http://10.125.66.44:9080
>       MobileFirst Server runtime: mfp
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation Direct Update authorization key:
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation test web resources for Android: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation test web resources for iOS: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation test web resources for Windows 10 UWP: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation test web resources for Windows 8 desktop: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation test web resources for Windows Phone 8: false
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation ignore file extensions for Android: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation ignore file extensions for iOS: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation ignore file extensions for Windows 10 UWP: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation ignore file extensions for Windows 8 desktop: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation ignore file extensions for Windows Phone 8: png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3
>       MobileFirst Platform Foundation language preferences: en

Cordova is clearly accessible from mfpdev, however the error message persists

Answer (score 1):

In MobileFirst 8.0 you need to install Cordova in the CLI apart from the MobileFirst CLI

Instructions in our getting started tutorials. Please see the link for more information.

```
Download and install NodeJS.
From a Command-line window, run the command: npm install -g cordova.
```

https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/setting-up-your-development-environment/cordova-development-environment/

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I already did every step un the tutorial. cordova -v gives me 6.1 as is written in the question.

Comment: can you remove the platform, re-add the platform, rebuild the platform and see it if works?

Answer (score 1):

Try

> ionic cordova build --prod

You will show you actual error, for which error msg is appearing.

Same problem I was facing, found, some missing resource in `config.xml` is making whole noise, by above method. Resolved that and done.

Comment: thank you this fixed my issue, app name was changed on config.xml. Reverting it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue while walking through the tutorial 'Getting started with Ionic and MobileFirst Platform Foundation 8.0 Beta' found on youtube.
I resolved the issue the with command on the shell

```
$> npm install -g cordova ionic
```

After that command

```
$> mfpdev app preview
```

started  to server the app in the browser as expected. I already had the cordova installed.