# IBM MobileFirst app preview return Error: The Cordova command-line interface is not installed on your system path

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I followed the IBM migration cookbook to migrate my hybrid apps to MobileFrst 8.0.

When I try to run **mfpdev app preview**, this error return :

```
Error: The Cordova command-line interface is not installed on your system path.
```

I run a check on the cordova and mfpdev, both are installed

[image]

when I try to run **mfpdev info**, I'm getting this
[image]

Update :
I just found that mfp-cli do not support cordova version 7, so I reinstall my cordova and mfp-cli

[image]

and now the **mpfdev info** command return the same error as **mfpdev app preview**
[image]

I have been googling and reading IBM website for weeks but still can't make it work. I found a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39473546/mobilefirst-8-0-cordova-cli-interface-not-found-in-app-preview-mac) but there is no answer too.

Comment: Does your cordova installation include cordova-plugman and cordova-cli? If not, please install them.

Comment: I just try to install cordova-plugman and cordova-cli, but still getting the same error saying cordova cli is not installed

Comment: Are you installing cordova globally ( npm install -g cordova ) ? Or are you installing it locally and is it not available everywhere?

Comment: I install it globally and I can find all the folders in the the npm's nodes_modules (cordova , cordova-cli, plugman, mfp-cli, mfpdev-cli)